# Looking for a Powershell script to enable SharePoint Server Publishing on all sites in a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, powershell

I'm looking for a Powershell script to enable the SharePoint Server Publishing site feature on all sites in a single site collection or all site collections.

Answer (score 6):

To activate the Publishing feature on all the sites in a site collection use the script below. Publishing Infrastructure feature must be enabled for the site collection first.

```
Get-SPWeb -Site "http://rootWebUrl" -Limit all | % {Enable-SPFeature "PublishingWeb" -url $_.url}
```

For all site collections in a web application:

```
foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites)
{
    #first enable the Publishing infrastructure feature
    Enable-SPFeature "PublishingSite" -url $site.url
    Get-SPWeb -Site $site.Url -Limit all | % {Enable-SPFeature "PublishingWeb" -url $_.url}
}
```

Comment: this tries to enable the feature at Web level, not site collection level, and fails ,of course, because it's not enabled at site collection level.

Comment: @alex-m PublishingSite is a site level feature and PublishingWeb is a web level feature.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked better for all sites in a web application. Although I had some sites that already had publishing enabled and I wasn't sure how to skip those.

```
$sites = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $yourWebApp -Limit All

foreach ($site in $sites)
{
    #first enable the Publishing infrastructure feature
    Enable-SPFeature "PublishingSite" -url $site.url
    Get-SPWeb -Site $site.Url -Limit all | % {Enable-SPFeature "PublishingWeb" -url $_.url}
}
```